# Get Android R class when passing value with annotation?

Tags: java, android, resources, annotation-processing

I have this annotation `BindPrefRes.class`

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface BindPrefRes {
    @StringRes int value();
}
```

Now when I use that annotation in any Android project like this:

```
@BindPrefRes(R.string.app_name) String appName;
```

And I'm trying to get the value with `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`

```
int value = element.getAnnotation(BindPrefRes.class).value()
```

I get the actual int (`2131230753`), which I understand is the expected behavior. But how do I parse this int back to field (`R.string.app_name`), or at least string representation of that field (`"R.string.app_name"`)?

The [source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/HendraAnggrian/breadknife) if I'm being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you should avoid doing so whenever possible, because the required information might not be available at all. For example, if Gradle (or other build systems) ever start supporting incremental builds with annotation processors, the `R` class might not be present on compilation path by the time your processor runs.

Long answer: there are two ways:

#### Ugly

1. Scan the source code for `R` classes
2. Iterate over every field in found `R` classes and add all constants to Map
3. Associate the value, received from annotation with constant from the Map

[One implementation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/4ad9f9888c4b62476591488cade3aacda80330ba/butterknife-compiler/src/main/java/butterknife/compiler/ButterKnifeProcessor.java) of this approach (which for some reason relies on non-public Javac internals) can be found in ButterKnife sources).

[Another one](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/blob/b1e1903307d143b22f985d61c8b8e552d9c1c291/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/internal/rclass/ProjectRClassFinder.java) is maintained by Android Annotations projects (you can copy it or access it directly by making your processor a plugin for Android Annotations processor).

#### Also ugly

Use Oracle proprietary semi-stable Trees API to directly introspect source code of `@BindPrefRes(R.string.app_name)`. I recommend going that way whenever possible, because it has fewer side-effects.

[Obtain a TreePath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Trees.html#getPath%28javax.lang.model.element.Element,%20javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror,%20javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationValue%29) for annotation value, cast it to ExpressionTree and manually parse contents.

Comment: I ended up manipulating ButterKnife's solution to achieve this. It works quite well, but I'm still baffled by what you mean by incremental builds potentially breaking this solution. Have you got a minute or two further explaining that? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Because constant values in annotations are inlined (as you have already observed). The class that contains the annotation does not really depend on R.java. Such implicit dependencies are major issue in practice (Gradle [completely disables it's incremental compilation](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/98d2250/design-docs/incremental-java-compilation.md) whenever it notices a change to inlineable public constant).